# SSL for multiple ports with single domain - ubuntu with nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl

I'm trying to setup SSL for multiple ports in Ubuntu with nginx. I have a domain `wpdev1.tk`. Currently it is working on with and without SSL. I have another web application which is running on same domain with different port. i.e. `wpdev1.tk:8080`. Currently this is working without ssl only. With SSL in port 8080 is not working. Below is my nginx configuration.

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
         server  unix:/run/php/php7.1-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    server_name  wpdev1.tk www.wpdev1.tk;

    set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/html/magento225;
    set $MAGE_MODE developer;
    include /var/www/html/magento225/nginx.conf.sample;
}




 #server {
       # listen 8080;
       # index  index.php index.html index.htm;
       # server_name  wpdev1.tk  www.wpdev1.tk;
       # root         /var/www/html/test;
   # }




server {

     listen 443 ssl http2;
     server_name wpdev1.tk www.wpdev1.tk;
     ssl on;
     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/wpdev1.tk/fullchain.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/wpdev1.tk/privkey.pem;


    ssl_protocols              TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers               'AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH:!aNULL';
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 24h;
    keepalive_timeout 300s;

  #include snippets/self-signed.conf;
  #include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Ssl-Offloaded "1";
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Port 443;
        #proxy_hide_header X-Varnish;
        #proxy_hide_header Via;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    }
}



server {

     listen 80;
     listen 8443 default ssl;
     server_name wpdev1.tk www.wpdev1.tk;
     index  index.php index.html index.htm;
     #ssl on;
     ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/wpdev1.tk/fullchain.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/wpdev1.tk/privkey.pem;


    ssl_protocols              TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers               'AES128+EECDH:AES128+EDH:!aNULL';
    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_session_timeout 24h;
    keepalive_timeout 300s;

  #include snippets/self-signed.conf;
  #include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8443;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Ssl-Offloaded "1";
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-Port 8443;
        #proxy_hide_header X-Varnish;
        #proxy_hide_header Via;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    }
}
```

Is there any I missed ?

**Update 1:**
   I have updated the question (I dropped off the 80 port configuration and added that into SSL config)

Now I'm getting below error when I'm trying to access,
**https://wpdev1.tk:8443/**

```
400 Bad Request
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
```

Comment: You have both, 8080 with and without SSL in your config, this won't work. Either redirect or drop 8080 without SSL. I'd recommend not to use 8080 with SSL, as it is http-alt, maybe try 8443 (https-alt).

Comment: @Lenniey Thanks for your comment. Still I'm facing some problem. I have updated my question. Please check it.

Comment: Why do you `proxy_pass` back to the same nginx server? Where is your real application?